# Create PDF Table of Contents with links to chapter of text

Tags: java, c#, pdf, itext

I create PDF document ant I have go problem with links to chapter of text. 
I use code of Bruno Lowagie from [here](http://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/columntext-examples-itext5/creating-table-contents-using-events#2783-createtoc2.java), but it's Java and I have got some difficulties.

I'm doing like this:

class TOCEvents

```
public class TOCEvents : PdfPageEventHelper
{

    //protected System.Collections.Generic.List<TitleTOC> toc = new System.Collections.Generic.List<TitleTOC>();
    protected Dictionary<string, int> toc = new Dictionary<string, int>(5);

    public override void OnGenericTag(PdfWriter writer, Document document, Rectangle rect, String text)
    {
        toc.Add(text, writer.PageNumber);
    }

    public Dictionary<string, int> GetTOC()
    {
        return toc;
    }

}
```

main

```
                    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
                {
                    String title = "This is title " + i;
                    Chunk c = new Chunk(title, f14);
                    c.SetGenericTag(title);
                    doc.Add(new Paragraph(c));
                    for (int j = 0; j < 50; j++)
                    {
                        doc.Add(new Paragraph("Line " + j + " of title " + i));
                    }
                }
                doc.NewPage();

                doc.Add(new Paragraph("Table of Contents", f24));

                Chunk dottedLine = new Chunk(new iTextSharp.text.pdf.draw.DottedLineSeparator());
                Dictionary<string, int> entries = ev.GetTOC();
                Paragraph p;

                foreach (KeyValuePair<string, int> entry in entries)
                {
                    Chunk chunk = new Chunk(entry.Key);
                    chunk.SetAction(PdfAction.GotoLocalPage(entry.Key, false));

                    p = new Paragraph(chunk);
                    p.Add(dottedLine);

                    chunk = new Chunk(entry.Value.ToString());
                    chunk.SetAction(PdfAction.GotoLocalPage(entry.Key, false));

                    p.Add(chunk);

                    doc.Add(p);


                }
```

I have got problems whith this:

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, int> entry in entries)
                {
                    Chunk chunk = new Chunk(entry.Key);
                    chunk.SetAction(PdfAction.GotoLocalPage(entry.Key, false));

                    p = new Paragraph(chunk);
                    p.Add(dottedLine);

                    chunk = new Chunk(entry.Value.ToString());
                    chunk.SetAction(PdfAction.GotoLocalPage(entry.Key, false));

                    p.Add(chunk);

                    doc.Add(p);


                }
```

What am I doing wrong? I can't set links to chapters of text. I think, that i'm using wrong `Dictionary<string, int>`. Where did i mistakes?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are creating a TOC like this:

```
| key       | page number |
|-----------|-------------|
| Chapter 1 |    1        |
| Chapter 2 |    5        |
| Chapter 3 |    7        |
| Chapter 4 |    9        |
| Chapter 5 |   10        |
```

You render this information like this:

```
Chapter 1 ................... 1
Chapter 2 ................... 5
Chapter 3 ................... 7
Chapter 4 ................... 9
Chapter 5 .................. 10
```

You do this in such a way that, when you click a title in the TOC, or a page number, you trigger a link to a named destination with name `Chapter X` where X is a number from 1 to 5.

Nothing happens when you click that link, and nothing should happen, because you haven't defined any destination with names `Chapter X` anywhere.

You have copied code that I wrote for you in Java, more specifically the [CreateTOC2](http://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/columntext-examples-itext5/creating-table-contents-using-events#2783-createtoc2.java) example. I wrote this example based on an example that was written in answer to your previous question [How to create Table Of Contents in iTextSharp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39037594/how-to-create-table-of-contents-in-itextsharp)

However, you overlooked the fact that the `TOCEvent` changed:

```
public class TOCEvent extends PdfPageEventHelper {

    protected int counter = 0;
    protected List<SimpleEntry<String, SimpleEntry<String, Integer>>> toc = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    public void onGenericTag(PdfWriter writer, Document document, Rectangle rect, String text) {
        String name = "dest" + (counter++);
        int page = writer.getPageNumber();
        toc.add(new SimpleEntry<String, SimpleEntry<String, Integer>>(text, new SimpleEntry<String, Integer>(name, page)));
        writer.addNamedDestination(name, page, new PdfDestination(PdfDestination.FITH, rect.getTop()));
    }

    public List<SimpleEntry<String, SimpleEntry<String, Integer>>> getTOC() {
        return toc;
    }
}
```

In this new TOCEvent, we keep track of a `counter`. Each time, a title is encountered, a new (unique!) name is created and the counter goes up.

```
 String name = "dest" + (counter++);
```

With this name, you have to create a named destination. In this case, we create a `/FitH` (fit horizontally) destination, at a specific Y position:

```
writer.addNamedDestination(
    name,  // the unique name
    page,  // the current page number where the title is added
    new PdfDestination(        // the destination on that page
        PdfDestination.FITH, rect.getTop()));
```

You do not add any such destinations, hence you can't link to any named destination in the document.

In my example, I pass the unique name to the TOC:

```
| key       | named destination | page number |
|-----------|-------------------|-------------|
| Chapter 1 |    dest0          |    1        |
| Chapter 2 |    dest1          |    5        |
| Chapter 3 |    dest2          |    7        |
| Chapter 4 |    dest3          |    9        |
| Chapter 5 |    dest4          |   10        |
```

When I create the TOC, I use these names, `dest0`, `dest1`,... to create actions like this:

```
PdfAction.gotoLocalPage("dest0", false)
PdfAction.gotoLocalPage("dest1", false)
PdfAction.gotoLocalPage("dest2", false)
PdfAction.gotoLocalPage("dest3", false)
PdfAction.gotoLocalPage("dest4", false)
```

You use the wrong values, you create links like this:

```
PdfAction.gotoLocalPage("Chapter 1", false)
PdfAction.gotoLocalPage("Chapter 2", false)
PdfAction.gotoLocalPage("Chapter 3", false)
PdfAction.gotoLocalPage("Chapter 4", false)
PdfAction.gotoLocalPage("Chapter 5", false)
```

That can never work, unless you use `Chapter 1`, `Chapter 2`,... as names for your named destinations. As you can't be sure those names will always be unique, I think that my approach is the better choice.

The answer to your question *What am I doing wrong?* is simple: you are creating links, but you forgot to create the destinations.

Comment: I have a question. How can I add Table of contents in to menu of PDF document. I tell about bookmarks, that locate on left border document. When I used `Chapter` and `Section` it created automatically. Should I create new question about it?

Comment: Bookmarks can easily be created by using the `PdfOutline` class. You are already creating *named destinations*. You can use those named destinations to create your outline tree.